# In computer security, what are covert and side channels?

Tags: security

What are covert channels and what are side channels? What is the difference between the two? I would really appreciate it if you provided examples of each along with your answer.

Comment: More complete answers can be found on the security stack exchange site: [Covert, Overt, and side channels](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113332/covert-overt-and-side-channels)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in this context a channel is a path for sensitive data (what you're trying to protect or keep secret) to escape through.  Fundamentally it is about who knows about it (whether the leakage is intentional or accidental)

A covert channel is a channel that is hidden.  This means that its existence is intentional, and additionally there is an intention to conceal or hide its existence from a person who is trying to protect the system by filtering or limiting data flow.  As an example, steganography.

A side-channel is a channel that exists incidentally to the otherwise secure flow of data, and is described by Andrew Cooper.

Comment: Hmm, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covert_channel) says: "Covert channels are distinct from, and often confused with legitimate channel exploitations that attack low assurance pseudo-secure systems using schemes such as steganography or even less sophisticated schemes to disguise prohibited objects inside of legitimate information objects."

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  I won't argue with Wikipedia.

Comment: A side channel can incidentally be used to create a covert channel. E.g. if there's a side channel that can be used to discover someone's password, the message sender puts the message in their password, then the recipient cracks the password to get the message.

Answer (score 13):

**Covert channel** is between two parties who want to share some data between them without others knowing that such a communication is happening. The channel they use is in general not meant for communication.

Fro example,a spy process(S1) on a system has access to sensitive data but is restricted from sending emails.

another adversary process(S2) has no access to the sensitive information , but can send emails.

The two agree on a covert channel , say the disk access times. That is , the S1 access some data (any data , not necessarily the sensitive one), that is far from S2's data in the disk. So when S2 accesses its data , it takes higher latency . S2 would interpret this as bit '1'.

To signal bit '0' , S1 would access a nearby data , resulting lesser access latency for S2 , thus interpreted as '0'.Once the entire information is thus transmitted , S2 emails the sensitive data to the enemy.

**Side channel** , on the other hand , is like a back door through which a spy can gain some secret information pertaining to the victim , without the victim being aware of it.

There is no communication here , only leakage of sensitive information through the channel.

For example, a spy "listening" to the power dissipations of a device can try to guess the secret key used by the device for encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about covert channels,  but side-channels refer to information leaking from a system through characteristics of the system's operation.

For example, some cryptographic algorithms are susceptible to a side-channel attack because the internal operation of the algorithm varies depending on the value of different parts of the key.  In some cases it's possible to get enough information from the timing of different parts of the algorithm to figure out bits of the key (or even the whole key) being used.

In this attack you're not using the crypto-system itself, but are observing it in action and gaining information from that observation.  That's a side-channel attack.

Another example of side-channel attack is the remote reconstruction of a computer monitor display by picking up the electromagnetic leakage from the back of a CRT using an appropriately sensitive antenna.

Answer (score 1):

A typical covert channel would be a strategic selection of numbers that are supposed to be random.  For example, an "evil" version of PGP could deliberately choose the session keys so that the first eight bits of the encrypted session key (sent with the message) match a group of eight bits in the private key indicated by the second eight bits.  Someone who managed to collect enough encrypted messages from such an implementation of PGP (and knew about the covert channel) would be able to reconstruct the private key.

Answer (score 1):

**Cover Channel** is like the **Confinement problem**.

Supose you have 3 process **A**,**B** and **C** all of them running in user space.

Suppose process **A** has some secret data that shares with process **B**, and process **B** wants to communicate the secret data to process **C**.

But imagine that process **B** is encapsulated or confine so he can not send any data using any usual way of communication between processes.

How to overcome this issue? 
Process **B** can try to communicate a binary bit stream as follows. To send a 1 bit, it computes as hard as it can for a fixed interval of time. To send a 0 bit, it goes to sleep for the same length of time.
Process **C** can try to detect the bit stream by carefully monitoring its response
time. In general, it will get better response when process **B** is sending a 0
than when process **B** is sending a 1. This communication channel is known as a
**covert channel**.